# bootstrap date picket datesDisabled in html not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
<%= text_field_tag :appointment_date , 
(Date.today + 3).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") , 
:data=>{:provide=>:datepicker, 
"date-start-date"=> "+3d",
"date-end-date"=> "+14d", 
"date-format":"dd/mm/yyyy", "date-dates-disabled": "['10/10/2017']"}, class: 'form-control', 
onkeydown: 'return false' %>
```

I have a rails text_field_tag which had bootstrap datepicker attached to it. All the properties are working fine, except for `date-dates-disabled`. Any idea what I would be doing wrong here?

Comment: Which bootstrap datepicker plugin you are using. Just a thought - Can you give a try to this - `"date-dates-disabled": "['10/10/2017']"}` to `"date-dates-disabled": ['10/10/2017']}`

Comment: Why can't you use datepicker initialization separately via jquery and keeps you view simple?

Comment: this was a version import issue. Thanks for your inputs.